# Basic TextFormat change is doing nothing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, textformat

Code:

```
var BoldTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
BoldTextFormat.bold = true;
weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName.defaultTextFormat = BoldTextFormat;
```

This seems very simple, but it is not doing anything! The text is not becoming bold at all.

Using `weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName.setTextFormat(BoldTextFormat);` does nothing also.

These `trace`s:

```
trace(weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName);
trace(weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName.defaultTextFormat);
trace(BoldTextFormat);
```

Result in this output:

```
[object TextField]
[object TextFormat]
[object TextFormat]
```

And this is the text field I am trying to make bold:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2f0B.png]

I have embedded the bold font:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSson.png]

What could possibly be wrong? There are **no** errors. Tracing the text field's text shows the correct text, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Are you changing the text in that field ? or is the default text in the TextField ? please show your code with the line where you are actually changing the text.

Comment: @prototypical I changed the text. It's just `weaponName.text = theName` in `Weapon`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to embed the bold font, your image shows 'Regular' font.

Ok, I figured out the magic here. Likely why it started working for you is that you actually set the bold font for your field.

But here's the magic.  In the library, right-click on the bold font and choose properties. Then go to the actionscript settings and enable :

export for actionscript

Next, in your code you need to add this line :

```
BoldTextFormat.font = "Times New Roman Bold";
```

That should work.

Sadly, the .bold of the TextFormat doesn't seem to automatically find the bold version.

Comment: Okay, the problem is with embedding as setting the size to something different works. I will accept this answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName.setTextFormat(BoldTextFormat);
```

`defaultTextFormat` applies to text that is added after you set the format, if you want to change the format of text that is already set you should use `setTextFormat`

Comment: Then `weapons[player.activeWeapon].weaponName` is probably not the same `TextField` as `weaponName` you show in the properties pane.

Comment: @proto yes, it is. @ Baris Yes it is, tracing its text shows the correct text

Comment: In your image, it doesn't show bold, it shows 'Regular'. Are you SURE you have the bold embedded ?

Comment: Okay, the problem is with embedding as setting the size to something different works. I will upvote this answer and ask a new question.